# Check Multiple if conditions in bat file/ and operator in bat

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I want something like this:- `if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 
&& %ERRORLEVEL% neq 255 GOTO Not closed by user` . But this syntax is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this? XP or higher required, of course...

```
if %errorlevel% GEQ 1 (
  if %errorlevel% NEQ 255 goto :NotClosed
  ::other statements go here, if you need 'em
  ::don't forget to close the parenthesis on the last statement ->)
```

To clarify further:

```
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
  ::commands you want to perform if 0 go here. Notice ->) 
else (
  ::We got here because errorlevel was GEQ 1 or less than one...watch out
  ::if you program returns negative errorlevels!
  if %errorlevel% NEQ 255 goto :NotClosed
  ::other statements go here. But don't forget the parenthesis ->)
```

Comment: How to check whether it is equal to 0? `if %ERRORLEVEL%==0` works?

Comment: Yes. But perform the check before the NEQ check. So, do the `if %errorlevel% EQU 0` first, then the NEQ 255.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's an answer for [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com/tccledes.htm) (a command interpreter that can also run such scripts), which supports the syntax from JSanchez's answer, for downwards compatibility, but also has two better alternatives of its own.

The alternatives are …

### … its own multi-line `iff` command

```
iff %ERRORLEVEL% GE 1 then
  iff %ERRORLEVEL% NE 255 then
     goto :NotClosedByUser
  endiff
endiff
```

With `iff` one doesn't have the caveats about variable expansion happening "too soon" that one has with parenthesized compound commands.

### … compound expressions with logical operators

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% GE 1 .and. %ERRORLEVEL% NE 255 goto NotClosedByUser
```

This has the advantage of being almost identical to what you wanted in the question.  TCC even supports `GEQ` and `NEQ` for compatibility.  Yes, it doesn't require the colon in the `goto` command.

### Further reading

- JP Software. [*IFF*](http://jpsoft.com/help/iff.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.
- JP Software. [*Conditional Expressions*](http://jpsoft.com/help/conditionalexpressions.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.

Comment: Ya, The second one is what I was asking for. Thanks.